# Is there a free and open source CDI/MDM solution?

Tags: php, mysql, crm, mdm

We would like to create a not so complicated solution for managing customer records. It should periodically import some customer data from source systems and merge records basing on the matching of some params (e.g. email, phone). Fuzzy matching will be a plus. It must provide some data interfaces for fetching data by 3rd party systems.

Does anyone know free and open source solution for such task? Related words are Master Data Management and Customer Data Integration.

I will prefer some PHP and MySQL based solution, not so overloaded by functions.

Answer (score 2):

Developing a comprehensive [MDM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190163.aspx) solution is a big task. It can take years. What you seem to be looking for can be done by open source ETL engines sucs as [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/), and [Talend](http://www.talend.com/index.php). The provide a lot of matching utilities and has tools for you to get data from multiple sources.

Comment: We would like to make the solution as easy as possible. A simple model to store the master (golden) records for customers with a pair of child entities . One or two source systems withous online sync, one or two client systems. Thats why I look for simple solutions with standard data models and interfaces.

Comment: Make sure you get good requirements on the definition of a master record from your stakeholders. I think you should definitely check out Talend.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard VERY good things about [Sugar](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/).  I think it can do what you want.  I haven't used it myself though.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to use Sugar CRM as a storage for master records that will be imported from other systems, and a tool for at least a manual deduplication.

Comment: In the company I worked at where it was used, I know they did a lot of import/export.  Being open source it's all documented.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PIMCORE](http://pimcore.org) for PIM or MDM solutions.  and it also offers DAM and CMS services.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [AtroCore](https://github.com/atrocore/atrocore) for it. This system has a completely configurable data model and can do exactly what you need. Data exchange can be automated via REST API.